# No img showing for mysql query and no stocknr when hovering

Tags: php, database, image

Having a problem uploading a picture from a database, wondering if i'm doing something wrong..

I've checked that the image is there by using `<img scr='/upload/imgpath.jpg'>`

Any suggestions?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT pic, stocknr, status FROM stock WHERE status = '1'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
{
$stocknr2 = $row1['stocknr'];
$picname = $row1['pic'];
$upfile = $picname;
echo "<center>";
echo "<a href='details.php?stocknr=$stocknr2'>";
echo "<img src='/upload/$upfile' border=1 width=350 height=280></a>";
echo "</center>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: You have a ; on the end of the `while` - `$result));`  remove it and it should loop.

Comment: Nice, Always good to have a second opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change while row;

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```